# Reactor: Use Mono<Void> or a dummy type like Mono<Boolean>

Tags: java, spring, project-reactor

I've got a REST service written in Java using Spring and associated libraries including Reactor, using Mono to wrap expensive operations.

I am refactoring DB related code with the usual CRUD methods. I've come across examples with a return type of `Mono<Void>`, which to me would make sense for methods where one only cares about success or failure. For my use case things like update or especially delete a database entry.

In actuality I've been hitting all sorts of friction in trying to use `Mono<Void>` which came to a head for me when I had an area where I had two methods that could be done in parallel, one of which was returning `Mono<Void>`, and when I went to use `Mono.zip` to combine the results that didn't work. And I couldn't find any method to combine them, maintain the parallelism, and use `Mono<Void>`. What does work is mapping the `Mono<Void>` to something like `Mono<Boolean>` with a dummy `Boolean.TRUE`.

So at this point I am wondering what the best practice is when the method doesn't have a real return type, just indicate success or error. Should I be trying to use `Mono<Void>` with some techniques I am missing or just use a dummy type like `Mono<Boolean>`?

Comment: Your question, at its core is "how do I use Mono<Void> and zip the results?", so why didn't you ask that and show an example? I suspect you already know the answer to this question. The key is in the word "dummy". If you have to use some dummy type, you probably went wrong somewhere.

Comment: If you only need to signal completion or error, `Mono<Void>` is the appropriate type. `Mono<Boolean>` would confuse anyone trying to read the code.

Answer (score 0):

> when I went to use Mono.zip to combine the results that didn't work

That is because you cannot zip something to nothing, the resulting mono will be empty.

[image]

Instead, you can use (1) `Flux.merge` and call `next` to convert the Flux to a Mono or (2) or let mono void to complete then play the other.

```
    Mono<Void> monoVoid = Mono.empty();
    Mono<Object> monoSomething = Mono.just("something");

    StepVerifier.create(Mono.zip(monoVoid, monoSomething))
        .expectNextCount(0)     // Note: zip results in empty mono
        .expectComplete()
        .verify();

    // Alternative #1
    StepVerifier.create(Flux.merge(monoVoid, monoSomething).next())
        .expectNext("something")
        .expectComplete()
        .verify();

    // Alternative #2
    StepVerifier.create(monoVoid.then(monoSomething))
        .expectNext("something")
        .expectComplete()
        .verify();
```